# How to change the Rect Transform of a panel in Unity using C#

Tags: unity, c#

I am trying to create a sort of menu for a game. I have put my main content on one panel and the menu contents on another. The menu panel is kept to the side of the main panel. I want to place a button on the main panel which when clicked would position the menu panel on top of my main panel. A button on the menu panel would push it back to its original position. What would be the script for these buttons?

Comment: RectTransforms are still Transforms. How would you place two GameObjects in the same position normally?

Comment: by capturing the transform.position.x in a variable and then changing the value.

Comment: So, apply that to your UI elements. It's the same deal.  If that doesn't work, you need to update your question as to *why* that doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set the exact local position of a RectTransform?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/139295/how-do-i-set-the-exact-local-position-of-a-recttransform)

Answer (score 2):

This worked:

```
public GameObject leadersPanel;
public void ShowLeaders()
    {
        leadersPanel.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = new Vector2(0, 0f);
    }
    public void ShowMain()
    {
        leadersPanel.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = new Vector2(-800, 0f);
    }
```