# RectTransform Button Start shaking with Vector3.MoveTowards()

Tags: unity, c#, gui

I have a RectTransform Button that i want to make it move to a de-terminated vector3.

To move the button i use this code (it is inside Update())

```
        int i = -1;
        foreach (RectTransform Button in Buttons)
        {
            i++;
            Vector3 NewPosBtns = new Vector3(StartButtonsVect[i].x, (StartButtonsVect[i].y + 192.5f), StartButtonsVect[i].z);
            Vector3 CurPosBtns = StartButtonsVect[i];
            Button.localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(CurPosBtns, NewPosBtns, AnimationSpeed);
        }
```

`Buttons` is a array and i add the button to the list using unity editor

`StartButtonsVect` is of vector3 that i add the using this code

```
void Start()
{
    foreach (RectTransform Button in Buttons)
    {
        StartButtonsVect.Add(Button.localPosition);
    }
}
```

For some reason the button start shaking instead of going to the target position (NewPosBtns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of `MoveTowards` is the *current* position of the object.

You've passed a variable called `CurPosBtns`, which might *imply* it's "current", but you initialized that variable to `StartButtonsVect[i]`. Which means despite its name, it's still representing the *start* position of the button, not the current position.

This means that every frame, `MoveTowards` thinks it's starting from scratch - it never has a chance to accumulate any progress because you always pass it the start position. So you only see one frame's worth of movement progress - which will wiggle back and forth based on frame timings (fast frames make very little movement progress, assuming you've scaled `AnimationSpeed` by `Time.deltaTime`).

The fix is to replace `CurPosButns` with the actual position, ie.

```
Button.localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(Button.localPosition, NewPosBtns, AnimationSpeed);
```

Also, for positioning elements on a canvas, [consider using anchoredPosition rather than localPosition](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/139295/how-do-i-set-the-exact-local-position-of-a-recttransform/139299). This tends to play nicer with UI layout and scaling behaviours.