# Unity WorldToViewportPoint not giving correct results

Tags: unity, c#, gui, coordinates

I have a script that places an UI element on the place where a 3d object is in 3d space. I do this in the following way:

```
public class test : MonoBehaviour {

public Camera MainC;
public GameObject testc;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    var ui = Object.Instantiate((GameObject)Resources.Load("uit"), Vector2.zero, Quaternion.identity);
    ui.transform.SetParent(GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Canvas>().gameObject.transform, false);

    var vertexs = testc.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.vertices;
    var trs = testc.GetComponent<Transform>();
    var cdc = new Vector2(GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Canvas>().GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta.x , GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Canvas>().GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta.y); 

    Object.Instantiate((GameObject)Resources.Load("pinksphere"), trs.transform.TransformPoint(vertexs[6]), Quaternion.identity); //bottomright
    Object.Instantiate((GameObject)Resources.Load("pinksphere"), trs.transform.TransformPoint(vertexs[5]), Quaternion.identity); //topleft

    var tl = MainC.WorldToViewportPoint(trs.transform.TransformPoint(vertexs[5]));

    var topleft = new Vector2(tl.x * cdc.x, tl.y * -(cdc.y) );
    ui.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = topleft;
}
```

}

But this does not place the UI Element on the desired position. See the following images for more explaination.

[image]

in this case i want the TOPLEFT corner of the UI element to be ontop of the pink dot at the TOPLEFT of the whitecube. But as you can see the Y-axis doesnt quite match..

Some extra information about the conditions like canvas used and the prefab settings. See images below:

[image]
these are the canvas settings.

[image]
this are the Main Camera settings.

[image]
and this are the UI prefab settings.

If you need any more information or something isnt clear let me know so i can clarify!
the code is really inefficient and ugly but it is only for testing purposes :)

Comment: Usually you'd want to parent a new UI element to the canvas, or to an existing UI element under the canvas, and set its AnchoredPosition [as described in this related Q&A](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/139295/39518) — have you tried something like that?

Comment: good suggestion about setting the parent first. I changed the code see updated question. But i still have the exact same problem..